# how to avoid word breaking inside a label?

Tags: html, css

I am styling label with css property but the problem is every word is breaking to new line inside label.For example `"Withdraw money"` is showing this way

```
Withdraw 
money
```

I tried all the property like `white-space:nowrap,float: left,display:inline-block,display:inline,` but nothing is working!one more thing,can anybody explain why the color property is not working for the text inside label?My code is below:

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
p,
td,
quote,
small,
form,
input,
ul,
li,
ol,
label {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #51555C;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 11px;
}
/* Form styles */

input,
select {
  padding: 3px;
  color: #333333;
  border: 1px solid #96A6C5;
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
select {
  width: auto;
  padding: 2px;
}
.formline {
  padding: 3px;
}
label {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #203360;
}
table {
  width: 400px;
}
td {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.input-container {
  padding: 8px;
}
#div-regForm,
.registered {
  border: 3px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 15px;
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) repeat-x #999933;
  color: #203360;
  margin: 15px auto 40px auto;
  width: 400px;
}
.form-title,
.form-sub-title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.form-sub-title {
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 6px 0 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-regForm">
  <div class="form-title">Withdraw money</div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="fname" style="color: #990000">Withdraw address</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-container">
            <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="fname" style="color: #990000">Amount</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="input-container">
            <input name="amount" id="amount" type="text" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: try `white-space: nowrap;` in css

Comment: that is in your CSS add `white-space: nowrap;` to `label`

Comment: @Lal, OP specifically stated that was already tried and he is already showing that in his code.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/tewvax3d/)..this is what i get from your code..

Comment: Sure looks like it is working for me. Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/p5qbrmt1/ You must have something else overriding the styles.

Comment: The code is working and does not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Fiddle is working fine but i am still struck in the same point as no solution is found.

Comment: If the code you've posted is working perfectly for us, there is not much else we can do when we cannot reproduce the issue.  [Is your HTML valid?](http://validator.w3.org)  Invalid HTML causes all kinds of strange issues.  Otherwise, carefully compare the source code of the working jsFiddle with the source code of your broken page and see which lines are different.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like 'Withdraw Money' is in a div. Try applying word-break: keep-all; to the div. Looks like the div is also missing white-space: nowrap;

Also check your divs' and labels' max-width and their parents' width as well. You could try applying word-break here too.

I can't comment and I'm not sure if this will help either, I am learning web development at the moment and I had to fiddle a lot with my website and those were the things that helped me :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        /* Page styles */

        body,h1,h2,h3,p,td,quote,small,form,input,ul,li,ol,label{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }

        body{
            margin-top:20px;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color:#51555C;
            height:100%;

            font-size:11px;
        }


        /* Form styles */

        input,select{
            padding:3px;
            color:#333333;

            border:1px solid #96A6C5;
            margin-top:2px;
            width:200px;
            font-size:14px;
        }

        select{
            width:auto;
            padding:2px;
        }

        .formline{
            padding:3px;
        }

        label{
            font-size:14px;

            display:block;
            text-align:left;
            white-space:nowrap;
            color:#203360;
        }

        table{
            width:400px;
        }

        td{
            font-size:11px;

        }

        .input-container{
            padding:8px;

        }


        #div-regForm,.registered{
            border:3px solid #eeeeee;
            padding:15px;

            background:url(images/bg.jpg) repeat-x #999933;
            color:#203360;
            margin:15px auto 40px auto;
            width:400px;
        }

        .form-title,
        .form-sub-title{
            font-size:40px;

            font-family:"Lucida Grande",Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size:20px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }

        .form-sub-title{
            font-weight:normal;
            padding:6px 0 15px 0;


        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div-regForm">
    <div class="form-title">Withdraw money</div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="fname" style="color: #990000">Withdraw  address </label></td>
            <td><div class="input-container"><input name="email" id="email" type="text" /></div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="fname" style="color: #990000">Amount</label></td>
            <td><div class="input-container"><input name="amount" id="amount" type="text" /></div></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I just copied and pasted your code. It simply works. (Tested in IE11,Chrome, and Firefox)
Just check your browser version